# Need some tips/advices about SQL (WITH command and maybe some optimizations)

Tags: postgresql

I was looking a way to select the first item from a `GROUP BY` in PostgreSQL, until I find this stackoverflow: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

There, I see that the `WITH` command was used.
I'm trying to understand some more "advanced" commands of SQL, like `PARTITION`, `WITH`, `ROW_NUMBER` etc. Until two or three months ago, I known only the basic commands (`SELECT`, `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, etc);

I have a little problem (resolved, but I don't known if this is the better way* to do).

*better way = I'm more concerned about a clean SQL code than the performance - this is just for a reports that will be executed once a day, and no more than 5000 records.

I have two tables, in PostgreSQL:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| TABLE NAME: point                            |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
|     km |      globalid |      lat |     long |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
|  36600 | 1553E2AB-B2F8 | -1774.44 | -5423.58 |
| 364000 | 25EB2465-1B8A | -1773.42 | -5422.03 |
| 362000 | 5FFDE611-88DF | -1771.80 | -5420.37 |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+


+---------------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE NAME: photo                                       |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| attachmentid |  rel_globalid |       date |    filename |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|            1 | 1553E2AB-B2F8 | 2015-02-24 | photo01.jpg |
|            2 | 1553E2AB-B2F8 | 2015-02-24 | photo02.jpg |
|          405 | 25EB2465-1B8A | 2015-02-12 | photo03.jpg |
|          406 | 25EB2465-1B8A | 2015-02-12 | photo04.jpg |
|          407 | 25EB2465-1B8A | 2015-02-13 | photo06.jpg |
|            3 | 5FFDE611-88DF | 2015-02-12 | photo07.jpg |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

So, for the problem:

Every `point` has **one or more photos**, but I only need the `point` data, and **first** and the **last** `photo`. If `point` has only one `photo`, I need only the first `photo`. If `point` has three `photos`, I need only the first and the third `photo`.

So, how I resolved:

First, I need the first `photo` of every `point`, so, I grouped by `rel_globalid`, and numbered every photo by group:

```
WITH photos_numbered AS (
    SELECT
      rel_globalid,
      date,
      filename,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY rel_globalid
        ORDER BY date
      ) AS photo_num
    FROM
      photo
)
```

With this code, I can get the 2th, 3th and so on too.

Ok, so, now, I want to get the first photo (still using the `WITH` above):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  photos_numbered
WHERE
  photo_num = 1
```

And to get the last photo, I used the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  p1.*
FROM
  photos_numbered p1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    rel_globalid,
    max(photo_num) photo_num
  FROM
    photos_numbered
  GROUP BY
    rel_globalid
  ) p2
  ON
    p1.rel_globalid = p2.rel_globalid AND
    p1.photo_num = p2.photo_num
WHERE
  p1.photo_num > 1
```

The `WHERE p1.photo_num > 1` is because if `point` has only one `photo`, this `photo` will appear as first photo, and last photo will be `NULL`.

OK, now I must "convert" the `SELECT` for the first `photo` and the last `photo` to a `WITH`, and do a simple `SELECT` with a `INNER JOIN` for the first `photo` and a `LEFT JOIN` for the last `photo`:

```
WITH photos_numbered AS (
    SELECT
      rel_globalid,
      date,
      filename,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY rel_globalid
        ORDER BY date
      ) AS photo_num
    FROM
      photo
), first_photo AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
      photos_numbered
    WHERE
      photo_num = 1
), last_photo AS (
    SELECT p1.*
    FROM
      photos_numbered p1
      JOIN (
             SELECT
               rel_globalid,
               max(photo_num) photo_num
             FROM
               photos_numbered
             GROUP BY
               rel_globalid
           ) p2
        ON p1.rel_globalid = p2.rel_globalid AND
           p1.photo_num = p2.photo_num
    WHERE
      p1.photo_num > 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  point.km,
  point.globalid,
  point.lat,
  point."long",
  first_photo.date     AS fp_date,
  first_photo.filename AS fp_filename,
  last_photo.date      AS lp_date,
  last_photo.filename  AS lp_filename
FROM
  point
  INNER JOIN
  first_photo
    ON
      first_photo.rel_globalid = point.globalid
  LEFT JOIN
  last_photo
    ON
      last_photo.rel_globalid = point.globalid
ORDER BY
  km
```

I think this SQL is huge for a 'simple thing'!

Is working? Yes, but I want some advices, some documentations that I can read and understand better, some commands that maybe I can use to make a "better" SQL (like I said, about two or three months ago I don't even know the `PARTITION` and `WITH` commands).

I tried to put a link for SQLFiddle here, but SQLFiddle never worked for me (always return 'oops' message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for clean SQL, then try lateral left join together with first_value and last_value window functionsinstead of common table expression (WITH clause):

```
select *
from point po
left join lateral 
(
   select first_value( date )     over( order by ph.date) as first_photo_date,
          first_value( filename ) over( order by ph.date) as first_photo_filename,
          last_value( date )      over( order by ph.date) as last_photo_date,
          last_value( filename )  over( order by ph.date) as last_photo_filename    
   from photo ph
   where po.globalid = ph.rel_globalid 
   limit 1
) q on true
;
```

an additional `count(*) over()` with a case expression can be used to "clean" values of last photo when there is only one record:

```
select *
from point po
left join lateral 
(
   select first_value( date )     over( order by ph.date) as first_photo_date,
          first_value( filename ) over( order by ph.date) as first_photo_filename,
          case when count(*) over () > 1 
               then last_value( date )    over( order by ph.date)
          end as last_photo_date,
          case when count(*) over () > 1 
                then last_value( filename )  over( order by ph.date) 
          end as last_photo_filename    
   from photo ph
   where po.globalid = ph.rel_globalid 
   limit 1
) q on true
;
```

Comment: tks! left join lateral is new for me! unfortunately, it's not compatible with postgresql 9.2 running here (don't ask me why they are running this version)!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from krokodilko, I made a new SQL query without `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`, because I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 (without `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  po.km,
  po.globalid,
  po.lat,
  po."long",
  ph.fp_date,
  ph.fp_filename,
  ph.lp_date,
  ph.lp_filename
FROM
  point po
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      rel_globalid,
      first_value(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ph.rel_globalid) AS fp_date,
      first_value(filename) OVER (PARTITION BY ph.rel_globalid) AS fp_filename,
      CASE WHEN count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ph.rel_globalid) > 1 THEN 
        last_value(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ph.rel_globalid)
      END AS lp_date,
      CASE WHEN count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ph.rel_globalid) > 1 THEN 
        last_value(filename) OVER (PARTITION BY ph.rel_globalid)
      END AS lp_filename
    FROM
      photo ph
    ORDER BY
      rel_globalid
  ) ph
  ON ph.rel_globalid = po.globalid
```

only thing I don't like it's `OVER (PARTITION)` in almost every `field` in `INNER JOIN`